# Six month stay in UK with passport

Tags: uk, passports, visa-free-entry

If I enter the UK on 1 January and depart six months later using my passport, what is the earliest date I can re-enter the UK for another six months?

Comment: You can enter the very next day. Good luck, you will need it.

Comment: @user92031 That proposed pattern of travel does not look very much like genuine ‘visiting’ - travellers with strong ties to their country of residence would normally find it difficult to be away for one period of 6 months, let alone two or more. If you decide to try this it would be best to follow UKVI advice for visa-free entry: bring the same documents you’d need to apply for a visa, to show to officers at the UK border.